# Skip sanitization for videos in html5lib

Tags: python, django, sanitization, html5lib

I am using a wmd-editor in django, much like this one in which I am typing. I would like to allow the users to embed videos in it. For that I am using the [Markdown video extension](http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2009/apr/02/python-markdown-extension-video/) here. The problem is that I am also sanitizing user input using html5lib sanitization and it doesn't allow object tags which are required to embed the videos.

One solution could be to check the input for urls of well-known video sites and skip the sanitization in those cases. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to append 'object' to `html5lib.sanitizer.HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_elements`. A great solution would be to subclass `html5lib.sanitizer.HTMLSanitizer` so you can conditionally accept or remove the object in `sanitize_token`.

The implementation seems [clear enough](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/source/browse/python/html5lib/sanitizer.py#140) to tackle.